# How to show send email message immediately in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, queue

I have tried a lot to show send message immediately,but it takes time.

I think queue is not working properly.

In app/config/queue.php I am using

'default' => 'sync'

Please help me out.I am confused what to so now.It is taking time to show success message but I want immediate success message

```
       $tasktime = new Tasktime();
        $tasktime->TaskTitle = Input::get('tasktitle');
        $tasktime->Description_Task = Input::get('taskdescribe');
        $tasktime->Estimated_Time = $case;
        $tasktime->Task_Status = Input::get('status');
        $tasktime->Priority_Task = Input::get('priority');
        $tasktime->Assignee_Id = Input::get('Assignee_Id');
        $tasktime->cat_id = Input::get('taskcategories');
        $tasktime->Task_DueDate = Input::get('duedate');
        $tasktime->Task_created_by = Auth::user()->firstname;
        $tasktime->Created_User_Id = Auth::user()->id;
        $tasktime->tasktype = Input::get('tasktype');
    $tasktime->unsc=$cnt;
        $tasktime->save();
        // send mail to assignee id
        $assigneeUser = User::find(Input::get('Assignee_Id'));
        Mail::send(array('html'=>'emails.send'),array('TaskTitle' => Input::get('tasktitle'), 'Priority_Task' => Input::get('priority')), function ($message) use ($assigneeUser) {
            $message->to($assigneeUser->email)->subject('verify');
        });

        return Redirect::to('toggle')->with('message', 'Email has been sent to assignee related to work');
```

Comment: so don't queue it, `Mail::send()` not `Mail::queue` http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail

Comment: Then also it is taking 8/10 seconds to show success message.I want it immediately.I am using laravel 4 version

Comment: are you using a local or remote mail server?

Comment: I am using remote server

Comment: that's quite likely to be a factor

Comment: not use a remote server.

Comment: send me proper configuration of local server

Comment: shall i send some fries with that?

Comment: I have configure but still it is not working.That's why I have ask you.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Queuing message means you are not sending it instantly. This process is done in background. To send the email instantly you can use:

```
Mail::send(array('html.view', 'text.view'), $data, $callback);
```

REF: [laravel 4.2 mail doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail)

Comment: let check me out this

Comment: Now What more I can do ,Please help me out

Comment: are you live or localhost? which smtp server you using?

Comment: localhost and 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com','driver' => 'smtp',

Comment: it usually take 3/4 second to show result when sending mails. its not only your code but also how fast smtp server is responding ...

Comment: Oh!How to make it quick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87113/discussion-between-himanshu-dwivedi-and-hmtareque).

Comment: as you are redirecting the page it might taking some time to load your page as well ...

Comment: May be.Thanks for your help